# How to debug a Delphi application with redirected output

Tags: delphi, debugging, stdout, io-redirection

I've got a console application that crashes with an I/O error 6 when the output is redirected to a file. It probably has something to do with the fact that the console application changes the text color, which doesn't make much sense in a file.

- This works: `c:\dir\app.exe`
- This crashes: `c:\dir\app.exe >out.txt`

When I supply `>out.txt` as a parameter in the IDE (`run\parameters\parameters\`), I just get `>out.txt` as a parameter.

How can I debug the application with the stdout redirected to a file instead of the console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Redirection is made by the command line interpreter, in windows it is cmd.exe

To debug the application, just launch a cmd.exe with propers arguments to launch your application and redirect the output, for example:

cmd.exe /c "yourapplication.exe >redirect.txt"

To make this happen from inside IDE in order to debug, configure cmd.exe as the host application (Run/Parameters):

[image: Run/Parameters dialog]

Put a breakpoint where you want to stop, and launch a new cmd.exe (Project/Load process) with "Run to first source" after load action:

[image: Load process dialog]

And you're done... the debugger must stop the application at your breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You could try remote debugging:

- at the beginning of the application, add a `ReadLn;` which gives you time to attach to the process from within Delphi
- start the application from a command line (specifying the >out.txt parameter)
- in Delphi, connect with the app process (`Run | Attach to Process...`), set a breakpoint and then switch to the application to enter a key

Hint: a debugger breakpoint can also be set in code:

```
asm
  int 3
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it isn't failing due to directory permissions.  Fully-qualify the output file path to somewhere that you're guaranteed to be able to write. Otherwise, Windows7 may be playing games with the directory. (VirtualStore stuff).